# Wix Convert older to Web Application (not virtual)

Tags: iis, web-applications, wix, directory

i'm trying to create a wix (MSI) prooject that copy a folder from usb device into inetpub/wwwroot default IIS folder (and i have done this by CustomAction with xcopy command). 
The next step that i've to do, is convert this folder in a web application but without using virtual application. In practice i would like to do the same thing that i would do if i click on the command "convert application" in IIS on a normal folder placed under wwwroot folder.
Could you help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use iis:WebApplication, it will convert your web directory or virtual web directory into a web application. Make sure the path to the folder you want to convert into a web application is correct. Considering the following snippet.

```
<iis:WebDir WebSite="DefaultWebSite" Id="RandomWebDir" Path="[PATH]/inetpub/wwwroot/Folder" DirProperties="DirProperties">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="RandomWebApp" Name="Folder" WebAppPool="RandomAppPool" />
</iis:WebDir>
```